# Web UI to Xen Cloud platform?

Tags: xenserver

I am an intern at a small company. I have only studied linux for one month so I have no great knowledge of coding and very little knowledge of programming.

I have been assigned to build a server with two virtual machines (one demo server and one development server). 
I have worked with Citrix Xen server in Windows and had no problem.
But now I have to find a web UI for Xen cloud platform that you can reach from any OS.

The company has mostly ubuntu and OS x.

I have read about Xen Orchestra, but it's installation guide are for Debian. 
And Zentific are for Debian too, cant find for Ubuntu OS.

I am as I written a newbee at everything with Linux and open source, so I would be very greatful for help.

If I don't find a solution for XCP I will try to work with vagrant and virtual box instead.

I have really tried for two days now to find a solution, so I really hope you can help me find a web ui for XCP that works for Ubuntu and OS x.

I hope I have described the situation clearly now.

Thanks

Comment: Firslty - Are you using Citrix XenServer or Xen? Secondly - I'm downvoting because you seem to have got as far as `I don't understand how to install them` and stopped. As a place for Professional IT, that shows a distinct lack of effort and investigation on your part.

Comment: sorry, I should have explained myself better. It sad that I get bad rep for that. I am an intern at a company and I have been assigned to help them set up a server for vm. They work in Linux and I have only basic experience from linux. I have work with citrix xenserver in windows and had no problem, but now I installed xen (not citrix) and have to find a web interface so that a person from any OS can log in to the server. I got scared away when I saw all the code, I could't see any solotion without knowing code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be rude but you said you only have 1 month of experience with Linux.  I don't know you or your previous experience but if I were to guide myself based on people who I've worked with who only have 1 month of Linux experience, setting up an orchestrating solution for VMs might be a bit much.  Why not try to make use of the built-in management tools instead?

We run open source Xen for virtualization purposes and although I have to admit I didn't do the setup, here's what I know:

- If you're coming from a Linux system, you should be able to manage the host using the "xm" command, i.e.:

[root@xen02 ~]# xm
Usage: xm  [args]

Control, list, and manipulate Xen guest instances.

Common 'xm' commands:

console              Attach to 's console.
 create               Create a domain based on .
 destroy              Terminate a domain immediately.
 dump-core            Dump core for a specific domain.
 help                 Display this message.
 list                 List information about all/some domains.
 mem-set              Set the current memory usage for a domain.
 migrate              Migrate a domain to another machine.
 pause                Pause execution of a domain.
 reboot               Reboot a domain.
 restore              Restore a domain from a saved state.
 save                 Save a domain state to restore later.
 shutdown             Shutdown a domain.
 trigger              Send a trigger to a domain.
 top                  Monitor a host and the domains in real time.
 unpause              Unpause a paused domain.
 uptime               Print uptime for a domain.
 vcpu-set             Set the number of active VCPUs for allowed for
                      the domain.

If you're coming from a Windows workstation OR you want a GUI to use when managing from Linux, there's (either by default or perhaps it requires additional configuration, not 100% sure) a VNC session you should be able to connect to.  That VNC session will give you a GUI to stop/start/restart VMs.  In my case:

[root@xen02 ~]# ps auxwwwf |grep xen02 |grep vnc
root     11319  0.1  0.1  71300  4068 ?        S     2012 379:31 Xvnc :X -desktop xen02.domain.com:X (root) -httpd /usr/share/vnc/classes -auth /root/.Xauthority -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport NNNN -pn

So xen02.domain.com is the FQDN of my system running Xen.  The :X represents the "Desktop number" in VNC speak.   The NNNN would  be the port number on which VNC listens to.  To connect to the VNC console, I would then open a VNC session to xen02.domain.com:NNNN and I'll see a nice GUI to manage everything.

HTH

Comment: Yeah, this is a pretty huge project to throw to an intern.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat.com/cloud   allows you to manage a variety of cloud platforms.  Alternatively,  [Open Xen Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxenmanager/)